Gradle execute Java code prior to build task
I have a project where I must set a certain SystemProperty before I begin my build task. However, the value for it varies every day.
As it stands, once the build task starts, I can no longer edit this property in a meaningful way (as the override gets ignored). As such, I'd like to do it beforehand.
To fetch the latest value for this property, I have code for an API call and will be extracting the value from the response.
This API call is within a Java class called "CallApi.java" within my "src/test/java" directory, under "com.test" package
I have it set up so that the function within CallApi.java returns a String, which I plan on setting as the value of the SystemProperty, before beginning execution.
My thought process is that if I can define a custom task to fetch the latest value for this property, then I can set it in the build.gradle directly using the "systemProperty" command as such:

systemProperty 'placeholder', customTask

then have Gradle execute the clean and build tasks.
Is this possible? If not, is there an alternate way to achieve this?
P.S.
I've tried this approach
import com.test.CallApi

task callApi {
    doLast {
        CallApi.getPropValue()
    }
}

with the getPropValue() function returning mock String data, but the import statement doesn't resolve

Yes, it's possible.
In overview, we want to (i) build the code with the API call, (ii) make the API call, then (iii) build the other code with the data from the API call. Note to do this, it's essential that you can build part (i) without the API data, otherwise you have an irreconcilable circularity.
The following is an outline of a recommended approach to get you started1.

First, separate your code if necessary so one part makes the API call, and another part uses the received data. The easiest way to do this is to have the API call code in one subproject of a multi-project build (the "API project"), and the code that needs the data from the API in a separate subproject (the "main project").

Add a main method to your API project code which will run the program and fetch the required data. Have it save the data to a file in a known location.

Add the Application plugin to the API project. Configure it to point to the main method which fetches the API data. This creates a task "run" in that project which will call the main method and save the API data.
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'fully.qualfied.name.of.api.main'
}


Add a new task to the main project which calls the API project run task and sets the system property:
task setSystemProperty {
    dependsOn ':apiProject:run' // run the run task first
    doLast {
        // Write code to read the created API data file and set system property
    }
}


Finally make sure it runs before your compile task:
compileJava.dependsOn setSystemProperty




1 This approach does not follow best practice in all respects but involves less configuration. Best practice advises against task dependencies between projects as such dependencies can be brittle in larger builds. The better way to do things is to export an additional artifact from the API project. Also, tasks should know their inputs and outputs for more robust code and to allow incremental building to work.

I have my project integrated with the Serenity framework, and also have a Jenkins job configured for it. Would making it a Multi Project build not mess up the job/framework functionality?

I imagine it will need some care to get right, though I am not familiar with either of those frameworks... depends what tests and tasks you have configured. I note you could do this without a mutliproject build by adding another Java source set, but you'd also have to review the interaction with those frameworks with that approach (and it's more fiddly) so I don't see any benefit to that. If you want to pull this off I don't see much alternative to figuring out a little how those frameworks interact with Gradle

Okay so through a lot of trial and error, I'm almost ready with this approach and have made a sub-module to make the API call. However. the dependencies that are needed aren't getting added and I keep getting the following

Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments

This is explicitly for the dependencies defined within the "submodule" or "allprojects" tags.
It doesn't work even if copy the buildscript, dependencies, and repository part from the main build.gradle over to the sub-module build.gradle
Any idea about this?

Sounds like the java plugin isn't applied.

Thank you so much! This works perfectly now, and I can make all the necessary calls.

Well done getting it all implemented.

Assuming your CallApi.java file is structured correctly, and it contains a static method getPropValue() that returns the latest value for your SystemProperty, you can create a custom task to call this method and set the SystemProperty.
import com.test.CallApi

task callApi {
    doLast {
        String propValue = CallApi.getPropValue()
        println "Latest value for SystemProperty: $propValue"
        System.setProperty('propertyName', propValue)
    }
}

build.dependsOn callApi
Replace 'propertyName' with the actual name of the SystemProperty you want to set, and adjust the package and method names as necessary.
In this script:
We define a custom task called callApi.
In the doLast closure of the task, we call the getPropValue() method from CallApi and store the result in propValue.
We print out the latest value for the SystemProperty (optional).
We use System.setProperty() to set the value of the SystemProperty.
Finally, we make sure that the callApi task runs before the build task using build.dependsOn callApi.
This setup ensures that the SystemProperty is set with the latest value fetched from the API before your build task starts.

So I did try something along these lines, and as I mentioned, the first problem I ran into was that the import statement itself wasn't resolving.
Googling says that the src/test/java package needs to be added to srcDirs, but that's also already in place. There was also something about adding the src/test/java directory to the classpath, but I'm not too sure what that means.
